# check if string contains specific character with number PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers, character

I'm having trouble with getting a specific text from a list of urls in PHP.
here is an example of the urls

```
$arrString = array(
"http://example.expl/text-t350/", 
"http://example.expl/text-t500-another-text/"
"http://example.expl/text-t20/text-example/"
);
```

I need only the 't' character with te number:
t350
t500
t20

I tried the following:

```
foreach ($arrString as $key => $value) {
 if (strpos($value, "t".filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) !== true ) {
     echo "Url with t price ".$value."<br>";
 }

}
```

But didn't worked ;(
Hope you can help me...

Thanks inadvance !

Comment: You need to use regular expression.

Comment: what do you mean ? can you show me an example maybe ?

Comment: using regex in php you can easily separate the  tnum from the url ... check this link you will get the resources ...  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

Comment: foreach ($arrString as $key => $value) {
 echo preg_grep("/p[[:digit:]]/", $key);

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regular expression, see example below:

```
$arrString = array(
    "http://example.expl/text-t350/", 
    "http://example.expl/text-t500-another-text/",
    "http://example.expl/text-t20/text-example/"
);

foreach ($arrString as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/text-(t\d+)/', $value, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[1] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`text-` Match literally 
`(` Capturing Group start 
`t` Match literally 
`\d` Match a digit
`+` 1 or more 
`)` Capturing Group end